# Getting parent Id when clicking new button from related list

Tags: apex, controller

Object A is the parent object and object B is child object. object B has new button override with VF page. when I am clicking the new button of obj B from related list A I need Obj A's Id. For this I have added following lines in controller

```
String str = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16);
Id myId = (Id)str;
```

This works for classic view for lightning view am getting Error like

> Invalid id: lightning/cb/re 
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Anyone knows about how to solve this?

Comment: There are many methods to get ID. You need to change your URL parse approach in lightning or use other method to get the id.

Comment: String retUrl = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().substringAfter('lkid');   

String parentId = String.isNOTBlank(retUrl) && retUrl.length() >= 16 ? retUrl.substring(1,16) : retUrl;

we can get the parent Id in both classic and lightning experience by using this .